# Return error message on $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular I make an $http request and would like to return an error message just not sure how.

In Express I would like to do the following (or similar) upon errors.

```
res.send(400, { errors: 'blah' });
```

In Angular I currently have this:

```
$http.post('/' ,{}).then(function(res) { }, function(err) {
  console.log(err) // no errors data - only 400 error code
});
```

How can I access "errors" (i.e. "blah") from within Angular?

Comment: please explain in more detail what you are wanting. Can send back custom headers from server to set http status and text if that's what you want. Overall objective is not clear. Another apporach is to send back messages within `success` as part of json, and react accordingly client side to those messages

Answer (score 1):

$http message provides, success and error function:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// this callback will be called asynchronously
// when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

If something goes wrong, like a server error, or another http erro the error function will be trigger and you can catch the error.

If something else trigger or you must provide some kind of feedback to the user, you can use the success method, but returning the data as domething else like this:

```
data {message: 'your message here', success: /*true or false*/, result: /*some data*/ }
```

Then in the success function:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  if(data.success) {
     // do stuff here
  }
  else {
    // show the error or notification somewhere
  }
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  //do stuff if error 400, 500
});
```

Comment: So you're saying there is no way to return feedback on http error?

Comment: I just posted how you should do this

Comment: I clarified my post a bit. Basically I would like to populate the "data" field that is in the error callback. However passing a second parameter to my Express res.send call (in this case errors: "blah") doesn't seem to land in the data field.

Comment: Well, you should let Server and HTTP erros rise into error block, and custom errors in the success block as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but.. I believe what you wanted was:

```
angular.module('App').factory('MainFactory', function($http) {
  return {
    post: function(something) {
      $http
        .post('/api', something)
        .then(function(result) {
          return result.data;
        }, function(err) {
          throw err.data.message;
        });
    }
  };
});
```

and from one controller

```
angular.module('App').controller('Ctrl', function($scope, MainFactory ) {
    $scope.something_to_send = "something"
    MainFactory
      .post($scope.something_to_send)
      .then(function(result){
        // Do something with result data
       }, function(err) {
        // showError(err);
    });
});
```